# Products deleted after Attribute set was deleted

Tags: products, attribute-set, delete

Well, this is what happened:

I created a new Attribute set called "Nuevos Productos", then I added 20 products to that set. After that, I deleted the set by mistake and all the products were deleted too. How can I solve this!?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a backup u can solve it, if not your best option is to enter them again.

You can try this module for the future:

https://www.yireo.com/software/magento-extensions/trashcan

Once it is installed you will be able to undelete products, it only works with the product that are deleted after the module is installed.

Comment: Thanks baconl. Yes, Trashcan is a great extension that I will install.

Ok, so I found a .csv file of the products I deleted and I imported it to Magento again. The import went ok, but now I realize that many things are not working properly:

1.- Accents changed to this, for example:  Pantalla AcÃºstica PortÃ¡til
2.- Meta Information were not imported
3.- When I change texts, titles and page layout in a product, it doesnt work. I flush all the cache, deleted from var/cache, reindex all data, even clear the browser cache and it doesnt work. Prices, stock and images works fine. what is wrong?

Comment: Your character set is the problem, make sure that you csv file uses the same character set as your database. UTF8 for example.